# What happens to the printf statements on a cross compiler for embedded devices?

Tags: microcontroller

What happens to the print statements on an embedded tool chain where the micro controller has no display attached to it? Does the program crash? What about all the other several c dependencies when we use the standard header files on a microcontroller with features that a modern computer does not have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends completely on how the libraries are set up. They may be output via SCI, they may be silently swallowed, they may even cause an undefined reference error on link.

Answer (score 3):

To use functions like [printf](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html#ga4c04da4953607fa5fa4d3908fecde449), you have to [attach STDIO (standard input/output) to a stream first](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html#ga793fcb8f10b6b8746d4186012929ddf1). I linked to the [stdio library for AVR](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html)'s.

In my opinion it is mostly a compatibility thing from the PC world (or for lazy programmers) and for most microcontrollers (considering RAM/ROM size) you are using a very heavy tool with large memory footprint to accomplish a relatively simple task. Most of the time you are better off by writing your own routine to do exactly what you need. Remember that `printf();` is an extremely powerful command and linking it into your code links all its functionality in, not just the single (few) thing(s) you actually require.

I believe on AVR, just including a printf sets you back about 1 or 2kB of flash, which is a lot on a 2 or 4 kB device and the AVR libraries are pretty well optimized.

Notice that not all std... libraries are 'useless', some of the functions in [stdlib.h](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdlib.html) are still very useful, like eg. the [`ultoa();`](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdlib.html#ga66e31b615d9ef1a19c452d64d7250112) which compiles pretty neat and small code.

Comment: `printf` long predates PCs, and it's available and used on many systems today that are not PCs. The basic UNIX program model is small programs connected by text pipes, and you put test into the pipe with `printf` (among others). Many programs don't need (and would be made worse by) GUIs.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the libraries you're using. E.g. if you're developing on the MSP430 with CCS, [you can printf() over JTAG](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Printf_support_for_MSP430_CCSTUDIO_compiler) (which is better than nothing if you have no other debug interface).

With mspgcc it will give you an undefined reference (and then you could implement your own printf() over UART, for example).

Answer (score 0):

If your printf statements are sending text to a serial port, the program won't know or care whether or not there is a terminal connected to the serial port.